# How to add a dialog box before execution of an apk

Tags: android, apk, android-dialog

I was wondering how some people add a `DialogBox` before execution of real software like `APK mania` does.

It shows a small `Dialog` with `APK mania` written and a loading circle besides it.

I want to know how they do it so I can also try it out.

Comment: hi! welcome to SO! please take a look at the help section of the site [how to ask](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: 1 image = 1000 words. You can't assume that everyone knows about all the applications and functionalities!